# database values not populating inside select2 while adding dynamic form field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to integrate 'add dynamic fields' in my form as same as the link below http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/ . Everything goes right except the database retrieved values are not showing inside select2 'added.field.fv' method for formTemplate. which is just working perfectly for datepicker as shown in official website. If anyone has clue for get work my select2 then it will be great help for me.

```html
<!-- The template for adding new field -->
<div class="panel panel-info hide form-group" id="taskTemplate">
  <div class="panel-body" style="background: #e0e0e0;">

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="input-group input-append date">
        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="examDate[]" placeholder="exam date" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="input-group" id="programPicker">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <?php echo get_phrase('select_program'); ?></span>
        <select id="program_id" name="program_id[]" onchange="return get_programs_batchs(this.value)">
          <option disabled selected value=""> <?php echo get_phrase('select_programs'); ?></option>
          <?php 
foreach($program_list as $row2):
?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row2['program_id'];?>">
            <?php echo $row2['name'];?>
          </option>
          <?php
endforeach;
?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is adding dynamic fields and formvalidation code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initialize the date picker for the original due date field
  $('#examDatePicker')
  .datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
  })
  .on('changeDate', function(evt) {
    // Revalidate the date field
    $('#taskForm').formValidation('revalidateField', $('#examDatePicker').find('[name="examDate[]"]'));
  });


  $('#taskForm')
  .formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    err: {
      container: 'tooltip'
    },
    icon: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
      'task[]': {
        // The task is placed inside a .col-xs-6 element
        row: '.col-xs-6',
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The task is required'
          }
        }
      },
      'examDate[]': {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'The exam date is required'
          },
          date: {
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            min: new Date(),
            message: 'The exam date is not valid'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  .on('added.field.fv', function(e, data) {
    if (data.field === 'examDate[]') {
      // The new due date field is just added
      // Create a new date picker
      data.element
      .parent()
      .datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
      })
      .on('changeDate', function(evt) {
        // Revalidate the date field
        $('#taskForm').formValidation('revalidateField', data.element);
      });
    }
    if (data.field === 'program_id[]') {
      //$(".programPicker").select2();
      data.element
      .parent()
      .select2()
      .on('change', function(evt) {
        // Revalidate the program field
        $('#taskForm').formValidation('revalidateField', data.element);
      });
    }

  })

  // Add button click handler
  .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
    var $template = $('#taskTemplate'),
        $clone    = $template
    .clone()
    .removeClass('hide')
    .removeAttr('id')
    .insertBefore($template);

    // Add new fields
    // Note that we DO NOT need to pass the set of validators
    // because the new field has the same name with the original one
    // which its validators are already set
    $('#taskForm')
    .formValidation('addField', $clone.find('[name="program_id[]"]'))
    .formValidation('addField', $clone.find('[name="examDate[]"]'))
  })

  // Remove button click handler
  .on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('.form-group');

    // Remove fields
    $('#taskForm')
    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="program_id[]"]'))
    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="examDate[]"]'));

    // Remove element containing the fields
    $row.remove();
  });
});
```

and, here is the result of above code after adding dynamic form fields

[image: program list are not loading inside select2]

Comment: Are you getting options in select list without select2

Comment: Yes, its working, when i remove the select2 from added.field.fv function. But i need select2 working because when the mass of data is loaded its not easier for the user to choose a specific one using scroolbar

Comment: I'm sorry but i have no idea what `added.field.fv` does. But have you tried `$("#program_id").select2()`

Comment: yes i have tried it already and it also not working. while i initialize the select2 in program_id my select2 options will empty. So its a bad luck for me